# Create classes when reading from multiple tables in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have tables in the database named

```
Students (StudentId,Name,Address)
Subjects (SubjectId,SubName)
Stud_Subjects (StudentId,SubjectId)
```

And I hv created c# classes for Student and Subject. I want to take data from Stud_Subjects table do i need to create another class named "Stud_Subject". How to add add properties to that class.

lets say I want to get data joining these tables and the result should be like this.

```
(StudentId,Name,SubName)
```

How to map these result into C# class. do i have to create another class with above three fields.

Comment: Is that a mapping table `Stud_Subjects`? Post the table definition

Comment: @SriramSakthivel i updated the table definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two classes is enough. One for `Student` one for `Subject`. It looks like  `Stud_Subjects` table is for "Many-Many relationship", you can implement that via a collection.

```
class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public List<Subject> Subjects { get; private set; }
}

class Subject
{
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }

    public List<Student> Students { get; private set; }
}
```

`Subjects` collection in `Student` class will have all the subjects which a student is mapped and `Students` collection in `Subject` class will have all the students which is mapped to current `Subject`.

You could also consider converting `List<T>` to `Dictionary<int, Student>` and `Dictionary<int, Subject>` for easy access them via their `Id`s

Comment: Thank u very very much dude.. I think it is the answer.

Comment: @Daybreaker Welcome, make sure you see my edit. thanks.